# Creating a summary report by group and quarter SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I need  to create a summary report of a transaction dataset with SQL in SAS

My dataset:

```
   -ID  Type    TAG QTR Amt
   -1234    WX  D   1   40
   -1234    WX  D   1   10
   -1234    WX  D   1   40
   -1234    WX  D   2   30
   -1234    WX  D   2   50
   -4444    I   G   1   80
   -4444    I   G   1   20
   -4444    I   G   1   50
   -4444    I   G   1   70
   -4444    I   G   1   30
   -4444    I   G   2   40
   -4444    I   G   2   20
```

I would like to get a summary report by ID and quarter like the below:

```
    -ID    Type    TAG     QTR1     QTR2
   -1234    WX      D       90      80
   -4444    I       G       250     60
```

I can't manage to get the sum by quarters in different columns.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      id
            , type
            , tag
            , sum(case when qtr = 1 then amt else 0 end) as qtr1
            , sum(case when qtr = 2 then amt else 0 end) as qtr2
from        tbl
group by    id
            , type
            , tag
```